# Monitor goes standby on Windows 7 x64 installation

Tags: windows-7, installation

I can't install Windows 7 x64 on my computer and can't finish the installation procedure, because after first restart during setup, my monitor goes standby and i can't see anything. Then computer restarts after few minutes.

My pc is:

ASUS P5Q DELUXE
with 2 x ATI Sapphire Radeon HD 4870 512 MB

Comment: Is your computer x64 compatible?

Comment: Of course it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that drivers integrated into windows 7 setup are bad. I took my video card to friends computer, different platform, and got the same results. Then i put other ati card, installed windows 7 with it, powered off, put my HD4870, boot and instaled drivers from ati site. Everything seems to be working.

Comment: Excellent troubleshooting!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Ok, I found a solution. When you press multiple times F8 at boot (just before Windows logo shows up), you got into the advanced boot loader settings. There is an option "enable low-resolution video(640x480)". With that option, I could recontinue and finish the Windows setup.

---

I have exactly the same problem. I asked for a solution here on MS forums:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproinstall/thread/754b6450-7a2f-49c5-9c2a-c78e310ee1d8

And someone else has asked the problem in the German MS forum:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/w7itproinstallde/thread/00a4d370-bb31-4d9b-adb3-d80ac21ac0aa?prof=required

Answer (score -1):

I would try contacting the store you bought it from, the manufacturer, or Microsoft regarding this issue. They can give you much more in depth information and problem solving then can be had in an answer.

Comment: As far as i know both motherboard and graphic card are compatible with Windows 7. Besides, i ran my pc for over a year with Windows XP and no problem.

Comment: Like I said, take it to someone. I'm not an expert on Windows installs, but there are people that deal with these issues all day every day.